# Add custom column to order create item grid

Tags: magento2

We wish to add the extra column Cost to the Items Ordered grid when creating an order in Magento 2. See image below.

[image]

Hopefully someone can help us out! I already tried creating a custom module overwriting the Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php file but haven't got it working as of yet.

What we want as outcome is the following:

[image]

At least the Cost column would be required, but eventually a calculated Margin would be great!

**Edit #1:**

Following @Nayem I have overwritten magento/sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/items/grid.phtml and the columns are created but I don't get a value as output. My file is now looking like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items\Grid
 */
?>

<?php $_items = $block->getItems() ?>
<?php if (empty($_items)) : ?>
    <div id="order-items_grid">
        <div class="admin__table-wrapper">
            <table class="data-table admin__table-primary order-tables">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th class="col-product"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-price"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-cost"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Cost')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-margin"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Margin')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-subtotal"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-discount"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Discount')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-row-total"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Row Subtotal')) ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col-action"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')) ?></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="even">
                        <td class="empty-text" colspan="100"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No ordered items')) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="admin__table-wrapper" id="order-items_grid">
    <?php if (count($_items) > 10) : ?>
        <div class="actions update actions-update">
            <?= $block->getButtonHtml(__('Update Items and Quantities'), 'order.itemsUpdate()', 'action-secondary') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <table class="data-table admin__table-primary order-tables">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th class="col-product"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-price"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-cost"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Cost')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-margin"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Margin')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-subtotal"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-discount"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Discount')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-row-total"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Row Subtotal')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col-action"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')) ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-total"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total %1 product(s)', count($_items))) ?></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="col-subtotal"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal:')) ?></td>
                    <td class="col-price"><strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatPrice($block->getSubtotal()) ?></strong></td>
                    <td class="col-price"><strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatPrice($block->getDiscountAmount()) ?></strong></td>
                    <td class="col-price"><strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatPrice($block->getSubtotalWithDiscount()); ?></strong></td>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
                <?php $i = 0 ?>
                <?php foreach ($_items as $_item) : $i++ ?>
                <tbody class="<?= /* @noEscape */ ($i%2) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-product">
                            <span id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span>
                            <div class="product-sku-block">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>:</span>
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ implode('<br />', $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data::class)->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()))) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-configure-block">
                                <?= $block->getConfigureButtonHtml($_item) ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-price">

                            <?= $block->getItemUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>

                            <?php $_isCustomPrice = $block->usedCustomPriceForItem($_item) ?>
                            <?php if ($_tier = $block->getTierHtml($_item)) : ?>
                            <div id="item_tier_block_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"<?php if ($_isCustomPrice) : ?> style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <a href="#" onclick="$('item_tier_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>').toggle();return false;"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Tier Pricing')) ?></a>
                                <div style="display:none" id="item_tier_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_tier ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($block->canApplyCustomPrice($_item)) : ?>
                                <div class="custom-price-block">
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                           id="item_use_custom_price_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"
                                           <?php if ($_isCustomPrice) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
                                           onclick="order.toggleCustomPrice(this, 'item_custom_price_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>', 'item_tier_block_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>');"/>
                                    <label
                                        class="normal admin__field-label"
                                        for="item_use_custom_price_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>">
                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Price')) ?>*</span></label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <input id="item_custom_price_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"
                                name="item[<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>][custom_price]"
                                value="<?= /* @noEscape */ sprintf("%.2f", $block->getOriginalEditablePrice($_item)) ?>"
                                <?php if (!$_isCustomPrice) : ?>
                                style="display:none"
                                disabled="disabled"
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                class="input-text item-price admin__control-text"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-cost col-price">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCost()) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-margin">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCost()) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-qty">
                            <input name="item[<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                                   class="input-text item-qty admin__control-text"
                                   value="<?= (int) $_item->getQty() ?>"
                                   maxlength="12" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-subtotal col-price">
                            <?= $block->getItemRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-discount col-price">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatPrice(-$_item->getTotalDiscountAmount()) ?>
                            <div class="discount-price-block">
                                <input id="item_use_discount_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"
                                       class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                       name="item[<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>][use_discount]"
                                       <?php if (!$_item->getNoDiscount()) : ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
                                       value="1"
                                       type="checkbox" />
                                <label
                                    for="item_use_discount_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>"
                                    class="normal admin__field-label">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Apply')) ?></span></label>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                        <td class="col-price col-row-subtotal">
                            <?= $block->getItemRowTotalWithDiscountHtml($_item) ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-actions last">
                            <select class="admin__control-select" name="item[<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>][action]">
                                <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select')) ?></option>
                                <option value="remove"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove')) ?></option>
                                <?php if ($block->getCustomerId() && $block->getMoveToCustomerStorage()) : ?>
                                    <option value="cart"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Move to Shopping Cart')) ?></option>
                                    <?php if ($block->isMoveToWishlistAllowed($_item)) : ?>
                                        <?php $wishlists = $block->getCustomerWishlists();?>
                                        <?php if (count($wishlists) <= 1) : ?>
                                            <option value="wishlist"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Move to Wish List')) ?></option>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                            <optgroup label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Move to Wish List')) ?>">
                                                <?php foreach ($wishlists as $wishlist) :?>
                                                    <option value="wishlist_<?= (int) $wishlist->getId() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($wishlist->getName()) ?></option>
                                                <?php endforeach;?>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php $hasMessageError = false; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($_item->getMessage(false) as $messageError) : ?>
                        <?php if (!empty($messageError)) :
                            $hasMessageError = true;
                        endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php if ($hasMessageError) : ?>
                        <tr class="row-messages-error">
                            <td colspan="100"> <!-- ToDo UI: remove the 100 -->
                                <?php foreach ($_item->getMessage(false) as $message) :
                                    if (empty($message)) {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="message <?php if ($_item->getHasError()) : ?>message-error<?php else : ?>message-notice<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($message) ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?= $block->getItemExtraInfo($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                </tbody>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <p><small><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getInclExclTaxMessage()) ?></small></p>
    </div>

    <div class="order-discounts">
        <?= $block->getButtonHtml(__('Update Items and Quantities'), 'order.itemsUpdate()', 'action-secondary') ?>
        <div id="order-coupons" class="order-coupons"><?= $block->getChildHtml() ?></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        require([
            'Magento_Sales/order/create/form'
        ], function(){
            order.itemsOnchangeBind()
        });
    </script>
    <?php if ($block->isGiftMessagesAvailable()) : ?>
        <script>
        require([
            "prototype",
            "Magento_Sales/order/giftoptions_tooltip"
        ], function(){

        //<![CDATA[
            /**
             * Retrieve gift options tooltip content
             */
            function getGiftOptionsTooltipContent(itemId) {
                var contentLines = [];
                var headerLine = null;
                var contentLine = null;

                $$('#gift_options_data_' + itemId + ' .gift-options-tooltip-content').each(function (element) {
                    if (element.down(0)) {
                        headerLine = element.down(0).innerHTML;
                        contentLine = element.down(0).next().innerHTML;
                        if (contentLine.length > 30) {
                            contentLine = contentLine.slice(0,30) + '...';
                        }
                        contentLines.push(headerLine + ' ' + contentLine);
                    }
                });
                return contentLines.join('<br/>');
            }

            giftOptionsTooltip.setTooltipContentLoaderFunction(getGiftOptionsTooltipContent);

            window.getGiftOptionsTooltipContent = getGiftOptionsTooltipContent;

        //]]>

        });
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit #2:**

Got it working by making two functions in Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php returning cost and margin and using these functions in the template!

Answer (score 2):

Override **vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml** file by your custom module. The path will be something like **Vendor_name\Module_name\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml**

See the below example -

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
            <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quantity</item>
            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
            <item name="merchant" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Merchant</item>
            <item name="school" xsi:type="string" translate="true">School</item>
            <item name="fundraiser" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Fundraiser</item>
            <!-- <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item> -->
            <!-- <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gift Card</item> -->
            <item name="giftcard" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gift Card</item>
            <item name="fee" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Service Fee</item>
            <!-- <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Amount</item> -->
            <item name="fundraised" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Funds Raised</item>
            <!-- <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item> -->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
            <item name="merchant" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-merchant</item>
            <item name="school" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-school</item>
            <item name="fundraiser" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-fundraiser</item>
            <!-- <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item> -->
            <!-- <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item> -->
            <item name="giftcard" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-giftcard</item>
            <item name="fee" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-fee</item>
            <!-- <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item> -->
            <item name="fundraised" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-fundraised</item>
            <!-- <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item> -->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Mm seems not to work for me.. No columns are added after editing the file.

Comment: Clear cache, run setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile

Comment: Magento is running in developer mode and I have done a setup:upgrade. I can see the module is active but I dont see any change for the item grid. I just copied your example. I will edit my post to let you know what I did.

Comment: Mm can't edit my comment, but I have updated my startpost @Nayem

Comment: Ah wait this does change the order view item grid, but I want to edit the order create view item grid!

Comment: Oh! My bad. Then you need to override "\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\items\grid.phtml" file.

Comment: Perfect thats working! Now I try to output the Cost attribute with <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCost()) ?> but that doesn't return anything, while getName or getSku works. Any idea?

Comment: Check if you have value for cost column in catalog product listing.

Comment: I have a value for cost column in listing.